# Inner Join MySQL table only yields first row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to load data from 3 tables combined. However, it is only showing the 1st row. Seeking advice on how to get the other rows showing:

MySQL tables:

**notification:**
col(to_interview): 64, 64, 64

**comment:**
col(interview_id): 64, 64, 64
col(body): I love her, I love him, I love both

**interview:**
col(interview_id): 64

PHP and MYSQL Code:

```
    $data['notification']=$this->db->query
    ("SELECT n.*, i.*, c.*
      FROM notification as n
      INNER JOIN interview as i on n.to_interview = i.interview_id 
      INNER JOIN comment as c on n.to_interview = c.interview_id
      WHERE n.to_interview='$interview_id'
      GROUP BY n.to_interview
      DESC");
```

However, I'm only getting the first row of result from **notification** and **comment**, although I have 3 that corresponds to the interview_id 64.

Advice is hugely appreciated.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

remove this

```
GROUP BY n.to_interview DESC
```

the group by usage limited your search query only to the first row.

Comment: I changed Group By to Order By, seems it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @user3192948, my bad, I missed the DESC. But if you're happy with order by thats fine too.